# Insert alias column name from snowflake into azure sql using azure data factory

Tags: azure, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, azure-sql-database, azure-data-factory

i have below select query which select values from multiple tables in snowflake and insert into the azure sql
i am using azure data factory for that...

```
select a.first_name as Name,  b.emp_id as Id from table1 a join table2 b on a.id=b.empId
```

there is already column created in azure sql for Name and Id
but pipeline failes with below message

```
Failure happend on sink side
Column NAME cannot found in the Physical data base.
```

i am able to create the mapping for the 'Name', but even after only Name value  getting inserted into the sql table. in this case pipeline succeed but not inserting other column value 'Id'.
in fact i am not able to add the mapping for other column  'Id'

Any resolution to this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Failure happend on sink side
> Column NAME cannot found in the Physical data base.

The error you are getting is if the Column is not present in SQL table and the name of the column ins improper you are using the mapping is case sensitive.

- Check you are using correct names.

Check if you are getting correct data preview for your query.

[image]

Then Under Mapping import the mapping and map the column accordingly.

[image]